# Стиль текста в TextSwitcher

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Имеется TextSwitcher, в котором я программно обновляю показываемый текст. Стиль для этого текста я устанавливаю через styles.xml:

```
textSwitcher.setFactory(new TextViewFactory(R.style.TemperatureTextView, true));
```

А это тот самый стиль:

```
<style name="TemperatureTextView">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

Стиль без проблем устанавливается, реагирует на изменения (к примеру цвет текста в styles.xml поменять) - всё нормально. Но он будто не видит maxLines и выходит, что если слишком длинный текст, то отрисовка происходит в 2 строки.

Comment: странно, но это должно работать. Посмотрите, не перекрываете ли вы этот стиль программно?